# ImageMagick: How to create torn page effect for specifc edges?

Tags: imagemagick

The ImageMagick documentation provides guidance on how to create torn page effects (https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#torn). However, in their implementation, all edges are torn. Suppose I wish to tear off only the bottom or top part of the image. How can I achieve such a thing using ImageMagick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply grow the top & sides by using `-extent` operator.

```
convert zelda.png -background pink -extent 148x138-10-10  extent.png
```

(Adding pink background for visibility on stack)

[image: extent.png]

Apply the effect from the Usage documentation.

```
convert extent.png \( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black \
    -spread 10 -blur 0x3 -threshold 50% -spread 1 -blur 0x.7 \) \
    -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite torn.png
```

[image: torn.png]

Then crop back to original image size.

```
convert torn.png -crop 128x129+10+10 output.png
```

[image: output.png]

### Update

If you do not want to use geometry, you can use a combination of `-border`, `-shave` & `-chop`.

```
convert zelda.png -bordercolor pink  -border 10x10 -gravity South -chop 0x10  extent.png
convert extent.png \( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black \
    -spread 10 -blur 0x3 -threshold 50% -spread 1 -blur 0x.7 \) \
    -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite torn.png
convert torn.png -shave 10x -chop 0x10 output.png
```

.. And of course, this all can be done with one command.

```
convert zelda.png -bordercolor pink  -border 10x10 -gravity South -chop 0x10  \
    \( +clone -alpha extract -virtual-pixel black -spread 10 -blur 0x3 -threshold 50% \
    -spread 1 -blur 0x.7 \) -gravity Forget -alpha off -compose Copy_Opacity -composite \
    -shave 10x -chop 0x10 output.png
```

Comment: Must the dimensions of the image be explicitly given (e.g. `148x138` and `128x129`)? Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to create a torn edge effect using ImageMagick. Here is another example command using IM version 6 and *nix syntax. This should apply a torn effect to just the top edge of any input image while keeping the original dimensions of the image.

```
convert input.png -alpha set -background black -fill white \
   \( +clone -colorize 100 -gravity south -chop 0x6 -splice 0x6 \
   -spread 6 -paint 2 +transparent white -blur 0x0.5 \) \
   -background none -compose dstin -composite torn.png
```

That creates a white mask inside the parentheses. Then a small amount of the "torn" edge is chopped off and a black strip is spliced on to replace it. The random-ish torn edge is created using "-spread" and "-paint" between the white and black areas of the mask. After that, outside the parentheses, that mask is used to apply the transparent torn area to the input image.

To apply the effect to the bottom edge, just change the "-gravity north" to "-gravity south".

To make the torn edge on the left or right, change the gravity setting to "west" or "east", and change the values of the "-chop" and "-splice" operations from "0x6" to "6x0".

This should work the same way using ImageMagick version 7 by changing the "convert" command to "magick".

To use it in Windows, remove the backslashes that escape the parentheses from "\(...\)" to "(...)", and change the continued line backslashes "\" to carets "^".